# Remove ID and add or change Language in object properties of PDF tag

Tags: pdf, tags

[image]I want to delete the **ID** and add or change the existing **Language** in the properties of PDF tags. Can anyone tell me how to do it using any of the languages **(Java/Python/Javascript only).**

I tried many ways but wasn't able to delete the ID and add or change the language.

Comment: But, I want to do this using Scripting or Java or Python.

Comment: [How to read/write metadata with pypdf] https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/metadata.html